# Keeping variable names for LLVM IR with swift compiler frontend

Tags: swift, clang, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-ir

I am very new to compiler development. For a project I need to find a way to keep the naming of the variables in my swift code for the LLVM IR. This is because I want to run an analyzer pass on the IR that makes use of those names.

I have tried this with self compiled Clang and found a flag "-fno-discard-value-names" that achieves this purpose. Is there anything that matches this functionality for Swiftc?

Comment: What you want is near the border between possible and impossible. Consider code such as `a = a + 1`. There will be at least two different IR `Value` objects that represent `a` before and after the addition. The two values will be in scope at the same time, and because they're different, they need different names. This may be a severe problem for you, or it may be easy to handle, depending on the details of what you're doing. There are other cases where the number of IR values doesn't match that of source variables. `b=a; c=a;` may become a single `Value` after a bit of optimisation. Good luck.

Comment: Using debug info is probably the best you can do, but keep in mind that it's not going to be a perfect match. The debug info points from the generated code to the source (names in this case), it doesn't block the compiler from generating code that has fewer/more values than there are variables in the source.

Comment: @arnt: Probably similar to `gcc -fverbose-asm` which annotates the asm with operand names.  Debug builds usually have the C var names when appropriate, but optimized builds very often have some numbered identifier that GCC invented during some compiler transformation passes, even if the register does take the same values from the same operations that one of the C variables did.  (But that's GCC.  clang's `-fverbose-asm` doesn't annotate each instruction.)

Comment: That sounds like a really neat feature to have.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to rely on debug info, by compiling with the `-g` flag.

The IR would have intrinsic calls, such as the one below,

```
%91 = extractvalue { i64, i1 } %90, 0, !dbg !257
...
call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i64 %89, metadata !245, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !247
```

that map values in the ir (`%91`) to high level debug information. Then it's easier to map that info to the source code, such as:

```
!258 = !DILocalVariable(name: "e", scope: !256, file: !19, line: 35, type: !246)
```

Be aware that there are other dbg intrinsics that may appear !